# JavaFX FXML - Getting MenuItem using fx:id

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am building the GUI of a Java application using Scene Builder. For each element, I have given it a `fx:id` so that I can refer to them later. I need to use `setOnAction()` on many of its elements such as:

```
((Button)mainPane.lookup("#submitButton")).setOnAction(e->{
    // ... code triggered when button is pressed ...
});
```

This works for most elements except `MenuItem`s. When I try the following, Eclipse tells me "Cannot cast from `Node` to `MenuItem`" and it does not work.

```
// Does not work
((MenuItem)mainPane.lookup("#about")).setOnAction(e->{
    // ... take user to about page ...
});
```

I see that `MenuItem` only extends `Object`, so it cannot be casted from a `Node`. How can I get back the `MenuItem` using its `fx:id`?

Note: I know I could use the `On Action` of FXML, but I want to utilize Lambda functions and keep the event-handling code in the same style.

Comment: Try looking it up from the `MenuBar`.

Comment: Use Sedrick's answer below. That way you can also declare all of your `MenuItem`s with the `@FXML MenuItem mnuAbout;` declaration. Much better than trying to lookup the `fx:id` for every node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((Button)mainPane.lookup("#submitButton"))` <- is a terrible idea.

If your nodes have an `fx:id`. You should do `@FXML YourNodeType yourNodeFx:Id;`

Example: In the FXML your `Button's` `fx:id="submitButton"`. Your `Controller` code should look like:

```
@FXML Button submitButton;
```

In your initialize method you should do:

```
submitButton.setOnAction(event ->{
    //Your code here!
});
```

Comment: To complete Sedrick's answer, the "tip" is just to make the name of variable controller side match the fx:id defined on FXML side (types must match!). JavaFX will make them match automatically. After that, it's up to you to add some action events or whatever you want as suggested.